# How can I tell if cdecimal is actually replacing decimal?

Tags: python

I have:

```
import cdecimal
sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal
```

Right before I create an instance of my application and before I use manage.py to run tasks, but how can I be sure that it is actually replacing decimal?

Comment: By doing what you've just done. The only way that possibly wouldn't work is if some other code you're running also tries to monkey-patch the `decimal` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the content of `sys.modules` directly:

```
print(sys.modules)
```

You can also check the name:

```
sys.modules['decimal'].__name__ == 'cdecimal'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you expect `decimal` to be replaced,

```
import decimal
help(decimal)
```

should spit out a comprehensive set of information.

The default system `decimal` begins with:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> help(decimal)
Help on module decimal:

NAME
    decimal

FILE
    c:\python27\lib\decimal.py
```

I expect your version should instead end up pointing to `cdecimal`.

Comment: I get *** No help on (decimal)